# Can't delete a table from dynamodb database using NoSQL Workbench

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I can't delete this table using the interface of NoSQL Workbench after clicking Delete button nothing happened.

ScreenShot

[image: 1]

I click on delete but nothing happened I was expecting the table will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a table used only for modelling or one that you have created as an actual table. If it's an actual table, ensure you have `DeleteTable` permissions for the role being used in workbench.

If this is just a modelling table locally, send feedback to the NoSQL Workbench team via the button on the main dashboard.

Comment: Yes i will send a feedback, because i was able to delete it using aws-cli.